# Is serial RJ45 to USB a standard?

Tags: usb, adapter, serial, rj-45

I can't find any resellers here in Sweden for the [RJ45 to USB](http://www.currentcost.com/product-datacable.html) cable from [Current Cost](http://www.currentcost.com/).

Are such RJ45 to USB cables covered by a standard so that I could buy one from another vendor?

<strike>It would also be great to know if it works in Linux / Ubuntu. It does. "Linux Kernel 2.4.31 and above already includes built-in drivers for PL-2303H, PL-2303XA/HXA and PL-2303HXD."</strike>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They are not covered by a standard, but they are not uncommon. Whether one has the same pinouts as another is anybody's guess.

Plus, note that this is not a passive cable:

> The cable includes the prolific (USB-Serial) chipset

Comment: Looks like I have to pay a silly 18 pounds for postage and packaging of a 8 pound cable then.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a 4$ knock off for nokia phones that also includes the prolific chipset cut off the nokia connector and crimp a RJ45 on it as long as you got the COST pinout.

See other custom cable here:
http://seriousrobotics.wordpress.com/2010/12/05/make-your-own-ftdi-cable-for-about-5/

Comment: I haven't got the pinout but I guess it wouldn't be too hard to try to figure it out or just to test a couple of different and hoping there will be no smoke.